# Convert price to string with specific string code in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I need assist, first maybe this have duplicate but i think i already searching and nothing found as i expected and wanted.

I confuse about my problem. What i wanted is converting number format to string format,

I have string called

```
$pricecode = 'ABCDEFGHIJ';
```

something like :

> ABCDEFGHIJ for number 1234567890

is for number from 0 to 9 and example like :

```
$price = 1500;
```

so i need price replacing and become :

```
AEJJ
```

Im trying to create code like below :

```
$priceCode = 'ABCDEFGHIJ';
$price = 1500;
$lenPrice = strlen($price);
$priceconveert = '';
$i=1;
$x=0;
while($i<=$lenPrice){
    $number = substr($Price,$x,1);                          
    if($number == 1){
        $priceconveert .= substr($priceCode,$x,1);                                        
    }else if($number == 2){
        $priceconveert .= substr($priceCode,$x,1);                                        
    }else if($number == 3){
        $priceconveert .= substr($priceCode,$x,1);                                        
    }else if($number == 4){
        $priceconveert .= substr($priceCode,$x,1);                                        
    }else if($number == 5){
        $priceconveert .= substr($priceCode,$x,1);                                        
    }else if($number == 6){
        $priceconveert .= substr($priceCode,$x,1);                                        
    }else if($number == 7){
        $priceconveert .= substr($priceCode,$x,1);                                        
    }else if($number == 8){
        $priceconveert .= substr($priceCode,$x,1);                                        
    }else if($number == 9){
        $priceconveert .= substr($priceCode,$x,1);                                        
    }else if($number == 0){
        $priceconveert .= substr($priceCode,$x,1);                                        
    }
    $i++;
    $x++;
}

echo $priceconveert;
```

With code like abode should be have result

```
AEJJ
```

but i have bad luck and result scrambled. Nothing like AEJJ and i would like if and can be done like `AEJ2` because behind `1500` **have 2 zero number (00)** and price code for `00` is `JJ` but make is short like `J2` or if have price `15000` that would be **J3 because have 3 zero (000)**.

I think if use array would be great, but i have no idea how to do it because about separate `numeric 1500 into 4 array` and `priceCode into 10 array`. I'm completely confuse.

Please help me, teach me how to resolve this. Thank You. I'm sorry for my language.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this,

```
$letters = array('A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J');
$numbers   = array('1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0');
$text    = '1500';
$output  = str_replace($numbers,$letters,  $text);
echo $output;
```

Output

```
AEJJ
```

[**DeEMO**](https://eval.in/469987)

To get back the number

```
$letters = array('A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J');
$numbers   = array('1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0');
$text    = 'AEJJ';
$output  = str_replace($letters,$numbers,  $text);
echo $output;
```

Output

```
1500
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/469990)

Comment: Amazing, and thank you. But one more question please. How letters if take data from mysql some like this ABCEDEFGHIJ and extra to array? Thank You

Comment: amazing.. now one more problem. I take ABCDEFGHIJ from mysql table. So how to extract it to array become array('A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J');

Comment: @Niranjan. you are amazing.. thank you very much... this solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju If I give AESSJJSS as input string in https://eval.in/470029 it shows output like AES4J2. Is it right ?

Comment: you tel me what you are expecting from this.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju It will display AES2J2S2

Comment: @VigneshBala it's that i'm looking for.. and it's correct for me.. but last question. When its become AEJ2 (1500) how to convert it again into 1500? Thank you. I try to use your code before but still confuse..

Answer (score 1):

After getting the character string (for price) you can use the following to display `AEJJ` like `AEJ2`

```
$string = 'AEJJ';
function howmanytimes($str,$char){
    $maxcount=0;
    $thiscount=0;
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($str);$i++){
        if(substr($str,$i,1)==$char){
            $thiscount++;
            if($thiscount>$maxcount) $maxcount=$thiscount;
        }else $thiscount=0;
    }
    return $maxcount;
}
$cnt = howmanytimes($string,'J');

if ($cnt > 1) {
    $r_string = '';
    for ($i = $cnt; $i > 0; $i--) { 
        $r_string .= 'J';
    }
    $n_string = 'J'.$cnt;
    echo str_replace($r_string, $n_string, $string);
} else {
    echo $string;
}
```

**EDIT**

[See my code](https://eval.in/470083) it will give you correct solution for string

Comment: That's i mean to... but that for specific character J. how if auto detect double character? like AAJE become A2JE or BEOOO become BEO3?

Comment: @Chandaka I will do but you ticked already the answer is right

Answer (score 0):

Use  [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) and try this

---

**Text to Price**

```
$priceCode = 'ABCDEFGHIJ';
$chars = preg_split('//', $priceCode, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$price = '';

foreach ($chars as $value) {

    switch ($value) {
        case 'A':
            $price .=   1;
            break;
        case 'B':
            $price .=   2;
            break;
        case 'C':
            $price .=   3;
            break;
        case 'D':
            $price .=   4;
            break;
        case 'E':
            $price .=   5;
            break;
        case 'F':
            $price .=   6;
            break;
        case 'G':
            $price .=   7;
            break;
        case 'H':
            $price .=   8;
            break;
        case 'I':
            $price .=   9;
            break;
        case 'J':
            $price .=   0;
            break;

        default:
            # code...
        break;
    }

}
echo($price);
```

**Output** `1234567890`

[phpfiddle Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xsnm-7k02)

---

**Number to text**

```
$priceCode      = array('A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J');
$number         = array('1', '2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0');
$price          = '19855';
$price_to_text  = str_replace($number,$priceCode,$price);
echo $price_to_text;
```

[Phpfiddle Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/3vib-5902)

Comment: Amazing... like number to text.. but i like if double number like 55 result EE become E2...

Comment: @Chandaka any problem ??

Comment: i do like number to text but text to price to long.. but good answer anyway.. i just need more explanation about array and take data text from mysql table and extract into array for each single character.. like from mysql table "ABCDEFGHIJ" extract to array so can be like array('A', 'B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J');

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$priceCodeVal = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J');
$priceCode = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0');
$price = '1500';
$priceconveert = str_replace($priceCode, $priceCodeVal, $price);
echo $priceconveert;
```

**OR**

```
$price = 1500;
$lenPrice = strlen($price);
$priceconveert = '';
$i = 1;
$x = 0;
while ($i <= $lenPrice) {
    echo $number = substr($price, $x, 1)." == ";
    if ($number == 1) {
        $priceconveert .='A';
    } else if ($number == 2) {
        $priceconveert .= 'B';
    } else if ($number == 3) {
        $priceconveert .= 'C';
    } else if ($number == 4) {
        $priceconveert .= 'D';
    } else if ($number == 5) {
        $priceconveert .= 'E';
    } else if ($number == 6) {
        $priceconveert .= 'F';
    } else if ($number == 7) {
        $priceconveert .= 'G';
    } else if ($number == 8) {
        $priceconveert .= 'H';
    } else if ($number == 9) {
        $priceconveert .= 'I';
    } else if ($number == 0) {
        $priceconveert .= 'J';
    } else {
        $priceconveert .= $number;
    }
    $i++;
    $x++;
}

echo $priceconveert;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pricecode = ['J','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I'];
$price = 1500;
$convert = str_replace(array_keys($price_code), $price_code, $price);
echo $convert;
```

Comment: Always good to have some explanation to your code and not just a block of code.